# Maschke-Wedderburn theorem for p*-rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(R,*)$ be a $*$-ring with 1 and with a proper involution $*$; meaning $aa^*=0$ only if $a=0$. Assume R is Artinian. An ideal $I$ is a $*$-ideal if $I^*=0$. Is it possible to define $*$-Jacobson radical for $R$ and derive a corresponding Maschke-Wedderburn Theorem for $(R,*)$?.
It follows that $ch(R)$ is $0$ or square-free. One needs to deacribe the old Jacobson radical in terms of $*$-quasi reglarity.

Comment: I assume you meant $I^*=I$?

Comment: (Also, I personally don't know of any "Maschke-Wedderburn theorem", and an internet search did not yield results, perhaps you could explain what you mean by that.)